# Migration of projects along with history and dependencies from PTC integrity 11.0 to 11.2 version

Tags: data-migration, alm, integrity, mks, mks-integrity

I have several projects in PTC integrity 11.0 that I am currently using. I have to migrate all the projects from 11.0 to 11.2 with out losing the traceability, revision history, item relationship or project level ACL's and triggers. Please advise if there is any way to carry out this type of migration.

Comment: upgrade your client according to your Integrity server, and copy the old client profile to ne client profile. This will keep all in working files. Upgrading server is done without loosing data. Full procedure should be provided by PTC Integrity support team. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to get SI projects along with its history and versions and if you are talking about IM projects then history and all cant be migrated.

So if you want to migrate history and versions of SI projects then you need to raise [PTC Integrity ticket](https://support.ptc.com/apps/case_logger_viewer/cs/auth/ssl/log) 
and provide below three files from the directory of the project that is being migrated:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 11.0 to 11.2 will not lose any data.

Obviously you should make sure you have a solid backup, just in case something bad happens.

Comment: Thank you for providing your inputs. However, the requirement is to migrate the projects with the revision history and traceability intact. It looks like the workflows and documents and the field relationships from the admin tool has to be migrated first, post which the projects from the integrity client should be migrated. There are no specific job aids or any process prescribed to carry out the same. Kindly help us with any details or explanations w.r.t the same.

Comment: I would suggest you contact PTC Integrity support for that level of assistance.